# Is the identity of Alias ever revealed in the game?

Tags: gravity-rush

In one of the cutscenes near the end of the game (episode 20 or 19), Kat had a vision that implied she recognized the identify of Alias when he removed his mask in the vision.  However, now that I've beaten the game, I still have not found any references to that.

Was the identity of Alias ever revealed to the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not revealed in the original Gravity Rush, the identity of Alias is confirmed in the sequel, Gravity Rush 2, to be

> Syd.

From the [wiki](http://gravityrush.wikia.com/wiki/Alias):

> it is revealed that his true identity is none other than Syd, a former attendant of Kat's during her time as Queen Alua in the pillar-top kingdom of Eto. He possesses a communications device made from Nevi crystal, the source of his ability to control the Nevi.

Answer (score 0):

No. A lot of the plot threads were left hanging and unanswered by in the ending. Probably will be answered in the sequel if that comes out. But there are clues into who he could have been. Such as Syd (too obvious in my opinion)... Or Chaz, the bomb disfusion specialist.